# javascript indexof regex A-Za-z0-9 always returns false

Tags: javascript, regex, indexof

I have created a JS fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/95r110s9/#&togetherjs=Emdw6ORNpc

HTML

```
<input id="landlordstreetaddress2" class="landlordinputs" onfocusout="validateinputentries()" />
```

JS

```
validateinputentries(){

landlordstreetaddress2 = document.getElementById('landlordstreetaddress2').value;

 goodcharacters = "/^[a-zA-Z0-9#.,;:'\s]+$/gi";

 for (var i = 0; i < landlordstreetaddress2.length; i++){

  if (goodcharacters.indexOf(landlordstreetaddress2.charAt(i)) != -1){

       console.log('Character is valid');

  }

 }

}
```

Its pulling the value from an input and running an indexOf regex expression with A-Z a-z and 0-9 with a few additional characters as well.

The problem is that it works with the entry of BCDEFG...etc and 12345...etc, but when I type "A" or "Z" or "0" or "1", it returns incorrectly.

I need it to return the same with 0123456789, ABCDEF...XYZ and abcdef...xyz

I should point out that the below does work as intended:

```
var badcharacters = "*|,\":<>[]`\';@?=+/\\";
badcharacter = false;

//firstname
for (var i = 0; i < landlordfirstname.value.length; i++){

   if (badcharacters.indexOf(landlordfirstname.value.charAt(i)) != -1){

        badcharacter = true;
        break;
   }

   if(landlordfirstname.value.charAt(0) == " "){

        badcharacter = true;
        break;
   }

}
```

Comment: Uh, that's not a regex. That's a string with a regular expression content. And `indexOf` is a string method, not a regex one.

Comment: The code also seems to fall prey to [The Horror of Implicit Globals](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html) *(disclosure: that's a post on my anemic little blog)*. Declare your variables.

Answer (score 1):

#### [`String.prototype.indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf)

> The `indexOf()` method returns the index within the calling String object of the first occurrence of the specified value, starting the search at fromIndex. Returns -1 if the value is not found.

So, you're trying to search this value `"/^[a-zA-Z0-9#.,;:'\s]+$/gi"` which "never" will be found in the entered string.

You actually want to test that regexp against the entered value.

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9#.,;:'\s]+$/gi.test(landlordstreetaddress2)
```

```js
function validateinputentries() {
  var landlordstreetaddress2 = document.getElementById('landlordstreetaddress2').value;

  if (/^[a-zA-Z0-9#.,;:'\s]+$/gi.test(landlordstreetaddress2)) {
    console.log('Characters are valid');
  } else {
    console.log('Characters are invalid');
  }
}
```

```html
<input id="landlordstreetaddress2" class="landlordinputs" onfocusout="validateinputentries()" />
```

Comment: I don't think that link is big enough.

Comment: It was meant as irony/humour. There's no need to make it an h3. (But obviously you're free to if you like! :-) )

Comment: @T.J.Crowder yes, I understood the irony/humour.  But, I've realized that it's was a huge text.!

Comment: So weird, then why does this work
    var badcharacters = "*|,\":<>[]`\';@?=+/\\";
    badcharacter = false;
    for (var i = 0; i < landlordfirstname.value.length; i++){
    if (badcharacters.indexOf(landlordfirstname.value.charAt(i)) != -1){
    badcharacter = true;

Comment: @TonyChapdelaine that's not ok.  What's the scenario? can you post that in your question?

Comment: I seriously hate this site and how its setup to ask questions. The suggested answer is basically what I am trying to do, but I am trying to understand why the way I have it setup in my question works for another snippet of code and it doesnt work here

Comment: @TonyChapdelaine I got it, now you're not using regex, therefore will work as you're expecting on.  Now you're comparing char by char different than the first approach in your question that was using a regex.

Comment: oh im such an idiot, okay, that makes sense now, thank-you all.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to combine two different methods of testing a string -- one way is with a regex; the other way is by checking each character against a list of allowed characters.  What you've wound up with is checking each character against a list of what *would* have been a regex, if you hadn't declared it as a string.

Those methods conflict with each other; you need to pick one or the other.

#### Check each character:

This is closest to what you were attempting. You can't use character ranges here (like a-zA-Z) as you would in a regex; you have to spell out each allowed character individually:

```js
var validateinputentries = function() {
  var address = document.getElementById('landlordstreetaddress2').value;
  var goodcharacters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789#.,;:' ";
  var badcharactersfound = false;
  for (var i = 0; i < address.length; i++) {
    if (goodcharacters.indexOf(address.charAt(i)) == -1) {
      badcharactersfound = true;
      console.log("not allowed: ", address.charAt(i));
    }
  }
  if (badcharactersfound) {
    // Show validation error here
  }
}
```

```html
<input id="landlordstreetaddress2" class="landlordinputs" onfocusout="validateinputentries()" />
```

#### Regular Expressions

The regex version is much simpler, because the regular expression is doing most of the work.   You don't need to step through the string, just test the whole string against the regex and see what comes out.  In this case you're looking to see if the input contains any characters that aren't allowed, so you want to use the character exception rule: [^abc] will match any character that is not a, b, or c.   You don't want to anchor the match to the beginning or the end of the string, as you were doing with the initial ^ and the trailing $; and you can leave out the + because you don't care if there are sequential bad characters, you just care if they exist at all.

```js
var validateinputentries = function() {
  var address = document.getElementById('landlordstreetaddress2').value;
  var regex = new RegExp("[^a-zA-Z0-9#.,;:'\\s]","g")
  var badcharactersfound = address.match(regex);
  // or the above two lines could also have been written like this:
  // var bad = address.match(/[^a-zA-Z0-9#.,;:'\s]/g)
  // In either case the "g" operator could be omitted; then it would only return the first bad character.
  if (badcharactersfound) {
    console.log("Not allowed: ", badcharactersfound);
  }
}
```

```html
<input id="landlordstreetaddress2" class="landlordinputs" onfocusout="validateinputentries()" />
```

Comment: `RegExp("[^a-zA-Z0-9#.,;:'\s]","g")` => `RegExp("[^a-zA-Z0-9#.,;:'\\s]","g")` or `/[^a-zA-Z0-9#.,;:'\s]/g`

Comment: Drat.  Thanks for pointing that out, I've corrected the answer.